# C Programming: How to create a linked list using a struct within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

So I'm trying to create a database of students with a struct with their names as the primary and other factors such as gender, age. Also in that struct, is another struct that contains the student's class grades: How would I do that?

Comment: i am not sure about what exactly is the question in here
you already solved your problem yourself

the moment you create a `students` struct, your `grades` struct inside that will already be available
only exception to this would be if the `grades` field was a pointer

Comment: do you mean `struct students` - it looks like it should be `struct student`

Comment: `struct grades;` seems to be missing something. `struct grades grds;` perhaps?

Comment: right now i am wondering how i did not saw those ...

Comment: If you are asking how you print the entire list of students with grades, I would suggest that you show us the code you tried and then we can help guide you on how to fix it.  As you attempt that code, think "recursion".  You call the function with the pointer to the first student, the function receives that as parameter "thisStudent", after the function prints that student's data, it then calls itself with thisStudent.student.

Comment: Please consider: where does the pointer `struct grades *grad` point? Do you ever set its value?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem in understanding is that you have your `students` structure wrong and it is misguiding you.  Look at this and try to understand how it works and why it is what you need and how you can use it to solve your problems:

```
struct student{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char gender[7];
    struct grades gr;
    struct student *nextStudent;
};
```

your print function, could look like this

```
void print (void){
    for(struct student *stud = root; stud != NULL; stud = stud->nextStudent){
        printf("Name: %s\n",stud->name);
        printf("Grades: %s, %s, %s, %s\n", stud->gr.math, stud->gr.history, stud->gr.science, stud->gr.writing);
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it, forgot to name it on here.

Comment: but still having problems the compiler says ‘grad’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

Comment: Look at the code I put in.  the proper way to address the grades structure that lives in each student, since you have named it gr, is to say `stud->gr`, then any member of that structure would be referenced like so `stud->gr.math`

Comment: it leaves the grade fields blank, didn't print them

Comment: You are looping through your list, and at any point, `stud` is a pointer pointing to the students you want to output.  You do not need a pointer to the `gr` grades structure.  To address it, you use the same thing you did for the name.  That is, to address the name (and output it), you used `stud->name`.  The same way, to address the `gr` that is part of the student structure pointed at by `stud`, you just use `stud->gr`.

Comment: Did you populate those grade fields with `stud->gr.math= ...`, or did you have some separate pointer to some other grades structure that you populated.  My guess is that when you populated the list, you did not really stick the grade into the `gr` that belonged to the student, but into some other structure that never made it into your list and went into la-la land.

Comment: You could show the code you used to populate a student, and I can help you understand why it has problems.

Answer (score 0):

if the question is 'how do I access the grades struct in student struct?' The answer is like this - assuming st is a student instnace pointer

```
st->grades.math[0] = 'A'
```